# Error en una Funcion

Tags: php, html

Tengo una base de datos creada con la cual quiero mostrar los datos de la tablas para ello e creado una Function

Esta es la Funcion

```
function listar($conexion,$consulta){
    $resul=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Error")
    $filas=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul)

         return $filas;
}
```

Esta seria la funcion creada hora la llamo de la siguiente manera y realizo la accion para mostrar los datos

```
$consulta""select * from jugadores";
$filas=listar($conexion,$consulta);
while($filas){
   echo"<tr>"
   echo "<td class='lis'>".filas["Dni"]."</td>;
   echo "<td class='lis'>".filas["Nombre"]."</td>;
   echo "<td class='lis'>".filas["Apellidos"]."</td>;
   echo "<td class='lis'>".filas["Nacimiento"]."</td>;
   echo "<td class='lis'>".filas["Categoria"]."</td>;
   echo "<td class='lis'>".filas["Foto"]."</td>;
$filas=mysql_fetch_assoc($resul);
   echo "</tr>";
```

Pero aqui viene el problema que cuando me voy a la pagina me da un error en $resul tal como este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque me muestra los datos, me da un erro y no puedo avanzar porque quiero volver a utilizar esa funcion para otra busqueda especifica pero con el error no puedo continuar

Comment: Si, el "error es correcto".  En el while tienes `$filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul);`, pero `$resul` no está definido previamente, comenta esa linea.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para poner el código como texto. En imagen es difícil de analizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

1. La función debería devolver un recurso de acceso a resultados o, si no quieres complicarte, [todas las filas obtenidas por la consulta](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)
2. El ciclo no tiene sentido, porque recibes un arreglo y luego tratas de recorrerlo como si fuera el recurso de acceso a resultados.

Me inclino por la opción de devolver todas las filas obtenidas:

```
function listar($conexion, $consulta) {
    // Ejecutar consulta
    $resul = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Error");
    // Devolver todas las filas
    return mysqli_fetch_all($resul, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Esto va a simplificar mostrar los resultados, porque solo necesitas un ciclo [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM jugadores";
$filas = listar($conexion, $consulta);
// Recorrer cada elemento de $filas y asignarlo a la variable $fila
foreach($filas as $fila) {
   echo"<tr>"
   echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Dni"] . "</td>";
   echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Nombre"] . "</td>";
   echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Apellidos"] . "</td>";
   echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Nacimiento"] . "</td>";
   echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Categoria"] . "</td>";
   echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Foto"] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```